# Apostrophe in a variable in SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following sql select statement which my variable $name does contain apostrophe (eg. ABC's), thus there will be an error.

Can someone kindly advise how can i change the sql statement to be able to retrieve information even though the $name contain apostrophe? I would only want to change directly in the sql statement. Thanks.

select * from tableA where name='$name';